# Android MotionLayout не показывает анимацию на реальном устройстве

Tags: java, android, анимация, kotlin

Я создаю анимацию в MotionLayout Editor в Android Studio 4.0.

У меня есть эта анимационная сцена:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/bt_authorization_login"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ll_login_password_container"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_authorization_forget_password"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ll_login_password_container"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Анимация в редакторе MotionLayout работает нормально. [image: анимация в редакторе]

Но когда я запускаю его на реальном устройстве, анимация не отображается. Я пробовал на разных устройствах.

Как запустить анимацию на устройстве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы ж ее в коде нигде не запускаете.

Нужно вызвать в нужном вам месте

```
motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
```

Comment: Да, точно, я нигде не вызываю. Спасибо!